# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' at main.js

Tags: nuxt3, primevue, vueuse, unocss

I'm facing this kind error in Console Dev Tool panel.
My project is Nuxt3. I can not fix this issue.
This error is showing in all pages.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to update my node version from 16v to 18v, but it didn't help.
And there is no any API requests coming from the backend side yet.

Comment: Not sure how you expect us to help you without any more details. Also, the latest LTS of Node nowadays is v20.

Comment: we can help you but you need to be more precise